# Why are JobIDs missing from _Job Data View?

Tags: marketing-cloud, automationstudio, data-views

We have pulled out email history from _Open Data View.

However, for most records - TriggererSendDefinitionObjectID is empty.

To understand which email was opened, we had no choice - but match on JobIDs from the _Job DataView.
So we started by querying _Job into a DataExtension, for intermediate results.

```
select JobID, EmailID, EmailName, EmailSubject, DeliveredTime
from _Job
```

When we manually search a specific JobID which exists in _Open, many are missing from _Job.

What does this mean?
What are we missing?
Also, is the fact that most TriggererSendDefinitionObjectID are missing is because List Sends / Manual sends don't get this populated?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2):

_Job data view is the only BU specific data view - and has no reference to subscribers. Hence you will only see the jobs which were performed from the BU in which you query it. Whereas for any other view - _Click, _Sent, _Bounce, etc., these are subscriber level activities, and hence the data views are global (you need to prepend them with ENT. when querying from a child BU).

You can filter records in these data views by querying `WHERE "OYBAccountID" = 'MID'` (MID being the BU you need the subset of data for)

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts. Good to know that. Thing is, there are no multiple BUs in this Marketing Cloud Account - AND I do see other jobs for some of the sends. In addition, in the full _Open data export the OYBAccountID is empty for all records...  Naveen has explained why jobs in _Job could be missing in _Open, I just can't see how I see jobs in _Open missing from _Job; I manually tested existence of jobs in the middle of the date range (3 months back) for jobs on the same date - some of the jobs show in _Job and others don't!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are right. Regarding the TriggeredsendobjectId the value will get populated only if the emails are sent via Journey / Triggered send. If the email is just a manual send / user initiated send then it won't get populated.

Regarding on Job Id are not matching with _Open and _job data view, there could be a chance where an email has sent to a small group of audience and if they haven't open the email then those Job Id will not be coming under the _Open data view.

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: oddly, it's the other way around - those in _Open do not appear in _Job !